# Functional Banana Traveller - What's wrong with my tick event?

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

I'm trying to implement a tick event, and have a little test below that demonstrates that it doesn't work. I'd appreciate insight as to why it doesn't work.

```
gameloop :: TChan UAC ->
            IO ()
gameloop commandChannel = do 
   (tickHandler, tickSink) <- newAddHandler
   networkDescr <- compile $ makeNetworkDescription commandChannel tickHandler
   actuate networkDescr
   forkIO $ forever $ (timer 10) >>= tickSink
   return ()


makeNetworkDescription :: forall t . Frameworks t =>
                          TChan UAC ->
                          AddHandler () ->
                          Moment t ()
makeNetworkDescription commandChannel tickHandler = do
   eTick <- fromAddHandler tickHandler
   bCChannel <- fromPoll $ grabCommands commandChannel

-- test fromPoll

   test <- initial bCChannel
   liftIO $ appendFile "testPoll.txt" $ show test

-- end fromPoll test

   let eCChannel = bCChannel <@  eTick
   liftIO $ print "hi there\n"
   reactimate $ (\n -> appendFile "Commands.txt" (show n)) <$> eCChannel


grabCommands :: TChan UAC -> IO [UAC]
grabCommands unval = do
   result <- (atomically $ readTChan unval) `untilM` (atomically $ isEmptyTChan unval)
   liftIO $ print $ show result
   return result

timer :: TimeOut -> IO ()
timer ms = do
   threadDelay ms
```

Here's some test data.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   commandChan <- atomically $ newTChan :: IO (TChan UAC)
   forkIO $ gameloop commandChan
   liftIO $ print "back from fork\n"
   atomically $ populateCC commandChan playerCommands
   return ()

populateCC :: TChan UAC -> [UAC] -> STM ()
populateCC pChannel pCommands = mapM_ (writeTChan pChannel) pCommands

playerCommands =
   [UAC (PlayerCommand (CommandData (T.pack "1" :: AID) Look) (T.pack "1")),
    UAC (PlayerCommand (CommandData (T.pack "2" :: AID) (Move Mongo)) (T.pack "2"))
   ]
```

when I execute the above `Main` I get this output.

```
"back from fork\n"
"[UAC (PlayerCommand (CommandData \"1\" Look) \"1\"),UAC (PlayerCommand (CommandData    \"2\" (Move Mongo)) \"2\")]"
"hi there\n"
```

The file `Commands.txt` never comes into existence. I attribute this problem to a faulty tick event.

I got my idea for the timer implementation from [this](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2010-November/005893.html), but wonder if I'm thinking about this the wrong way. Any ideas?

Edit: I wanted some assurance `fromPoll` was doing the right thing. I added the test above, and it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that the problem is not with the tick event, but with the fact that you model the player commands as a `Behavior`.

If you think denotationally and imagine that a behavior is a time-varying value `Behavior a = Time -> a`, does it make sense to model player commands in this way? What is the player command in, say, the time frame between `3s` and `4s`? Does the argument you give to `fromPoll` respect these semantics?

The thing is that `grabCommands` has a serious side effect: calling it removes the commands from the channel, so it is not even idempotent. Also, it *blocks* when there is no command available. I think that this is ultimately the reason why the tick event doesn't work: the network is blocked trying to execute the `fromPoll` action. However, the underlying problem is more profound: the right way to model player commands is to use an `Event`, not a `Behavior`.

Comment: That prompts the question of how to introduce buffered input, which I will discuss shortly.

Comment: I see how grabCommands has to go away, and I think accumE will help me sort out the problem of buffered input.